# Can the paper-progress element in Polymer be configured to display a circular progress?

Tags: polymer, paper-elements

The demo in the paper-progress element from Polymer shows only horizontal bars. But the Material design referenced by the element doc includes a circular shape. Can the paper-progress element be configured to display a circular shape? If not, what is the best way to add that functionality?

Comment: Did you checkout paper-spinner?